# JavaScript callback execute in main thread

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-jsom

I am using a JSOM SharePoint call to get some values from a list.  Once I get the values in the callback I want to execute the code in the main method of the thread.  How do I do that?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

It is javascript, **callbacks execute in the main thread**.

<sub>I suspect that's not your actual issue and you are having some problems with the async nature of the call and/or closures. If so, please extend your question to provide more information on your exact problem.</sub>

Comment: I am trying to update the UI on the callback, render some checkboxes, is this possible?  Or is there some way in which I have to switch to the main thread?

Comment: Yes, this is a very common scenario. There is no "main thread", javascript asynchronicity is not multithread based. Everything happens in the same thread (disregarding web workers & co for the moment).